# A complicated SQL Server CTE situation: Finding the root parent record

Tags: sql-server, database, common-table-expression

This is a lengthy but I've bolded the important stuff.

So I have scoured the net (including here) on building a proper CTE in sql server 2012. I have found a variety of resolutions that address on how to build one but from what i've noticed (and yet to discover) is a CTE with inner joins. I am not sure if that is a game changer but my attempts at it has brought me to a wall. Therefore I bring my dilemma to this community in hopes someone has insight. I'll try to be as thorough as I can to help everyone understand where I am coming from.

In my work I am tasked with creating a brand new alarm acknowledgement GUI because the default one that comes with our software (Wonderware Archestra IDE) is too small for our operators to make use on their touch screens. I'm supposed to reinvent the wheel with a touch screen menu system that you'd see in bars. The operator would select an alarm and click acknowledge. And a GUI filled with acknowledge options pops up.

The GUI I am creating would pop up and present a list of buttons at the top that displays the name of each section in the plant (the root parent) that is associated to the alarm. Clicking on the button would open a list of buttons under it be it an alarm acknowledgement reason or a sub folder for them to dive further for a more specific reason. I got the second part done and I'm fine tuning the first part where the graphic would query the database to retrieve all associated parent records to an alarm.

**Below is the original query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT urg.reas_grp_desc, urg.reas_grp_id, urg.parent_reas_grp_id
FROM [MESDB].[dbo].[util_reas_link] url  
inner join [MESDB].[dbo].[util_reas] ur on ur.reas_cd = url.reas_cd  
inner join [MESDB].[dbo].[util_reas_grp] urg on urg.reas_grp_id = ur.reas_grp_id    
where url.raw_reas_cd = @reasoncode
```

**The result of original query:**

```
reas_grp_desc   reas_grp_id parent_reas_grp_id
General         0           NULL
TestSubFolder9  129         128
```

**[util_reas_link]** is the table that contains all possible alarms (primary key) and all associated acknowledgement reasons (foreign key).

**[util_reas]** is the table that contains all possible acknowledgement reasons (primary key) and all associated sections and subsections of the plant (foreign key).

**[util_reas_grp]** is the table that contains all sections and sub sections of the plant (primary key) and each record has a primary group id and a parent group id. If the record has null in the parent group id then it is the root parent of that section.

This query worked until the plant wanted more acknowledgement reasons in a finer grade. The reason is that the old query only checked who was the parent and grandparent folder of that acknowledge reason. Now the depth can go far like 9 folders deep.

***My revised query (and dilemma) is this:***

```
;WITH CTE_REASON_GROUP
AS
(

SELECT urg.reas_grp_desc, urg.reas_grp_id, urg.parent_reas_grp_id,  1 as Lvl, urg.reas_grp_id as [RootGroupId]
FROM [MESDB].[dbo].[util_reas_grp] urg
where urg.parent_reas_grp_id is null
UNION ALL 
SELECT urg.reas_grp_desc, urg.reas_grp_id, urg.parent_reas_grp_id, cterg.Lvl+1 as Lvl, cterg.RootGroupId
FROM [MESDB].[dbo].[util_reas_link] url  
inner join [MESDB].[dbo].[util_reas] ur on ur.reas_cd = url.reas_cd  
inner join [MESDB].[dbo].[util_reas_grp] urg on urg.reas_grp_id = ur.reas_grp_id  
inner join CTE_REASON_GROUP cterg on cterg.reas_grp_id = urg.parent_reas_grp_id 
where url.raw_reas_cd = @reasoncode

)
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM CTE_REASON_GROUP      order by reas_grp_id
```

I know WHAT is happening. I know that the anchor is retrieving all the root parents. And I know that the second inner query (the original query with another inner join to link CTE_REASON_GROUP) is retrieving only records that is both associated to @reasoncode and the CTE_REASON_GROUP's reas_grp_id which yields no results. This is due to the fact only two records were retrieved as seen from above and neither one's parent_reas_grp_id would match the anchors retrieved records reas_grp_id.

**The result is simply the anchor's results:**

```
reas_grp_desc       reas_grp_id parent_reas_grp_id  Lvl RootGroupId
General             0           NULL                1   0
Pouring Station     1           NULL                1   1
Melting             2           NULL                1   2
Spray Booth         4           NULL                1   4
Core Room           10          NULL                1   10
Splitter            11          NULL                1   11
Stamper             12          NULL                1   12
Hot Wheel Grinding  13          NULL                1   13
Hub Cutting         14          NULL                1   14
Heat Treat          21          NULL                1   21
Core Baker          25          NULL                1   25
```

I KNOW I am close to the answer. But I cannot seem to bridge the gap from CTE to the results I want. From the original query General I don't have to worry about because it is a root parent with reason codes within it. TestSubFolder9 however is 9 subfolders deep with a test reason code. Its root parent is CoreRoom.

**The result I am seeking is this because TestSubFolder9's root parent:**

```
reas_grp_desc       reas_grp_id parent_reas_grp_id  Lvl RootGroupId
General             0           NULL                1   0
Core Room           10          NULL                1   10
```

While lengthy, I hope this helps everyone here to understand what I am trying to accomplish and what puzzle piece I am missing to get the record I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inverse the CTE like this to go up the hierarchy:

```
;WITH CTE_REASON_GROUP
AS
(
SELECT urg.reas_grp_desc, urg.reas_grp_id, urg.parent_reas_grp_id, 1 as Lvl, cterg.RootGroupId
FROM [MESDB].[dbo].[util_reas_link] url  
inner join [MESDB].[dbo].[util_reas] ur on ur.reas_cd = url.reas_cd  
inner join [MESDB].[dbo].[util_reas_grp] urg on urg.reas_grp_id = ur.reas_grp_id  
where url.raw_reas_cd = @reasoncode
UNION ALL 

SELECT urg.reas_grp_desc, urg.reas_grp_id, urg.parent_reas_grp_id,  cterg.Lvl+1 as Lvl, urg.reas_grp_id as [RootGroupId]
FROM [MESDB].[dbo].[util_reas_grp] urg
inner join CTE_REASON_GROUP cterg on urg.reas_grp_id = cterg.parent_reas_grp_id 
--where urg.parent_reas_grp_id is null

)
SELECT * FROM CTE_REASON_GROUP
order by lvl desc --reas_grp_id
```

Comment: @AlexKuderyashev - you sir are a genius. This is EXACTLY what I needed. I knew it was something blatantly obvious. I just needed another pair of eyes to see what I was doing. A slight alteration to what you suggested such as using Distinct in the "SELECT * FROM CTE_REASON_GROUP order by lvl desc" and moving a lil bit of the columns but other than this is awesome. THANK YOU SO MUCH!